# disable zoom for Smartphones

Tags: html, zooming, dygraphs

I am using the last version of dygraph on my web page, I updated it last week, and in the computer looks great, as well as in tablets but I am having some problems with smartphones. The graph does wired things when you click any where in the screen. As a quick solution I thought I could disable the zoom events or the click events while I have time to look at it and find a better solution.

I have done a research but everything I have found is this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/dygraphs-users/XqeoS3UAIQk

Where the solution is: See the interaction demo, I have looked for it but I don't find anything!

Any suggestions?? anything to disable the zoom or click events or better option for a quick solution would work!!

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that thread, Robert is suggesting that you copy the options for the "No interaction model" chart from http://dygraphs.com/tests/interaction.html.

There's currently some jankiness in the way that dygraphs handles touch interfaces. To disable it, you could try putting this code before you instantiate your dygraph:

```
Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel.touchend = Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel.touchmove = Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel.touchstart = function() {};
```

Comment: I tried to edit the response, but it says the edit queue is full. For the latest version of dygraphs, the code would be `Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel.touchend = Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel.touchmove = Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel.touchstart = function() {};`.

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer, thanks @HansEJC

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand @danvk's answer with an example...

You need to specify an empty object for the interactionModel property.

```
var mygraph = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById('nameofdiv'),
    stringofdata,
    { interactionModel:{}, otheroption:whatever }
);
```